# VS Code JS/TS automatically update imports when I move something from one file to another

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to automatically update imports in VS Code of things that are moved from one file to another? I am not sure if it is possible to do with the replace tool of VS Code, since it is not just a replace, it is a multiline update

Example:

```
import { someObject, anotherObject } from 'file1';
import { thirdObject } from 'file2'
```

When I move `someObject` from `file1` to `file2`, I would like to somehow add a new line with the correct import or update the existing one that imports from the new file. This should happen on all places that are importing `someObject` from `file1`

The above code should transform into:

```
import { anotherObject } from 'file1';
import { someObject, thirdObject } from 'file2'   // update the existing one
```

Or:

```
import { anotherObject } from 'file1';
import { someObject } from 'file2'       // add a new line
import { thirdObject } from 'file2'
```

If there is no existing import from the new file `file2`, it should obviously create a new line with that import, but If there is already an import from `file2`, it would be better to update it instead of creating a new line (if possible)

Comment: only tangentially related and not actually related to this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50187